# javascript - Ignorar espaços em branco da string

Tags: javascript

Tenho esta função em javascript e preciso que ignore os espaços em branco da string. Acho que a função está removendo os "blank spaces". Alguém sabe como uso essa mesma função sem remover os espaços em branco?

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    if (name !== "" && name !== null && name != undefined) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace("/\+/g", " "));
    } else {
        var arr = location.href.split("/");
        return arr[arr.length - 1];
    }

}
```

Comment: Eu não entendi nada, você fala primeiro "preciso que ignore os espaços em branco" e depois "sem remover os espaços em branco". Você poderia explicar melhor o que desejar, fornecendo um exemplo de input e output do resultado desejado?

Comment: Olá Guilherme,
O 13dev resolveu a função.
Tenho a string "TÊNIS DE MESA" que trazia um resultado null.
Agora com a nova função ele traz com os espaços em branco.
Obrigado!

Comment: Embora tenha resolvido, ficou bem confuso a pergunta. _blank spaces_ e _espaços em branco_ são a mesma coisa. rs

Comment: não achei nada confuso, a função tem que ignorar a presença de espaços em branco, isso é, virar as costas pra eles :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando o paramentro name existir estas a retornar o seguinte:

```
return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace("/\+/g", " "));
```

Então essa linha esta a comparar o resultado se não for nulo ira passar pela função `decodeURIComponent()` e estas a passar como argumento `results[1].replace("/\+/g", " "` o mesmo que remove os espaços em branco

podes simplesmente substituir por `results[1]` e o teu problema será resolvido

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    if (name !== "" && name !== null && name != undefined) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : results[1];
    } else {
        var arr = location.href.split("/");
        return arr[arr.length - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá 13dev, tudo bem?
Era isso mesmo que eu queria fazer, seu código está correto, a função incluiu os espaços em branco.
Obrigado man!!

Comment: se te ajudou marca a resposta, de nada!

Comment: Só faltou a explicação do que vc fez no codigo 13dev! Tem que mostrar o link para ele entender o que é marcar a resposta como aceita  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo editado

Comment: +1 pelo esclarecimento